# The click event from javascript on a button doesn't fire

Tags: javascript

So, I was going through a tutorial on event handlers. I created a button as instructed and then when I click on it, I wanted an alert to be displayed. Thats it. But it wouldn't work. Here's my html code:

```
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

And here's my javascript code:

```
var myButton = document.getElementByID("submit");
myButton.onclick = function(){
alert("YOu clicked on this button");
    }
```

I am using external js file and I've included it in the html from the head of the document.

Comment: It's close; use `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`

Comment: Use document.getElementById('submit'); instead

Comment: You need to learn to use your browser's error console. It would have told you that `document.getElementByID` is not a function. And once you fix that problem, it will tell you whatever else is going wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`document.getElementByID("submit");` -- it's `Id` instead of `ID`

Edit: I feel very bad for giving this one-liner as an answer, so to add to what others have said about learning how to use the browser's console as a debuggining tool, you should try to find an IDE/text editor with auto-completion to save you such headaches especially when you're just starting out.

Comment: So I figured out how to use Safari web inspector.Now that I correct it, it says "Null is not an object(myButton.onclick = function(){
 alert("YOu clicked on this button");)"

Answer (score 1):

You may have an issue where `document.getElementById()` is happening before the element is created on the page. Try including your JavaScript in an onload event, or include it after the button in your HTML.

Comment: That worked. I'd give one vote for your answer but apparently it isn't allowed for new users to vote. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

it maybe a typo. It is `getElementById` not `ID`

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, use document.getElementById("submit") with lower case Id. Also, you may want to use setAttribute so the alert fires when the button is pressed instead of immediately opening a popup when the alert line is encountered.

```
<script language="javascript">

    var myButton = document.getElementById("submit");
    myButton.setAttribute("onclick", "alert('You clicked on this button')");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change from `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById` and make sure your script stay below all the elements in the body. Example:

```
<body>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
    myBtn.onclick = function()
    {
       alert("this is a click event button");
    };

</script>

</body>
```

or you can put the script inside the `<head></head>` by add this event below to your script:

```
function initialize()
{
  // paste your code in here
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",initialize,false);
```

Hope it work!